# Option to generate DDL in Azure SQL DW

Tags: sql, ssms, azure-synapse

Couldn't find an option to generate DDLs from SSMS in Azure SQL DW(Synapse).
Is there any alternative approach to get the same using tools like sqlcmd or some other tool?

Answer (score 0):

From the Object Explorer, you right click on an individual object.

[image: SSMS single object scripting options]

If you want to script the entire database, you can right-click on the database name and select **Generate scripts...** which starts the script wizard.
[image: SSMS Generate scripts scripting option]